# How to connect json files downloaded from api?

Tags: python, json

I am downloading hundreds of files which have a format:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "Lines": "130",
            "Lon": 21.0566243,
            "VehicleNumber": "1000",
            "Time": "2020-12-22 18:55:03",
            "Lat": 52.1812215,
            "Brigade": "1"
        },
        {
            "Lines": "311",
            "Lon": 21.0817553,
            "VehicleNumber": "1001",
            "Time": "2020-12-22 18:54:52",
            "Lat": 52.2407755,
            "Brigade": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

My desired output is a list of dictionaries

```
[
    {
        "Lines": "130",
        "Lon": 21.0566243,
        "VehicleNumber": "1000",
        "Time": "2020-12-22 18:55:03",
        "Lat": 52.1812215,
        "Brigade": "1"
    },
    {
        "Lines": "311",
        "Lon": 21.0817553,
        "VehicleNumber": "1001",
        "Time": "2020-12-22 18:54:52",
        "Lat": 52.2407755,
        "Brigade": "2"
    }
]
```

combined from all the files.

What is a proper way to handle it?

I tried downloading with

```
def download(file_name):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_data,file_name), 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(response.json(), outfile)
```

But then I got one file with a couple of dictionaries with `{"result":}` and can't even load it as a json. Should I save each json in a separate file instead of making it just one file? If so, should i make a list of names for function download?

Comment: You are asking a few different questions and it isn't clear which you are having difficulty with. Is it the loading from the file, the converting from Json. Please see this post on how to ask a good question, and I'm certain you will get the help you need; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want each response to be a list of the dictionaries or if you want one big list written to the file.

You can collect all dictionaries just by creating a list and using `.extend`. That's one large list with dictionaries.

```
hold_list = []
# your API loop here
    resp = response.json()
    hold_list.extend(resp['result'])
print(hold_list)
```

If you want a list of lists, use `.append` instead of `.extend`. Play around with it to see the difference.

After that, you can dump it into a file as a JSON:

```
with open("output.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(hold_list, fp)
```

Lastly, if you want to write to the file each time you get the response from the API, you can write `resp['result']`. But that gives a list for each API response, and you'll need to either write a delimiter or put in a new line character or you may end up with a list after list with no spaces or delimiters in-between. This won't be JSON, but you can use Python and manipulate it as a list with dictionaries.

However, it is possible to get a JSON as well.
For example, like this (gets a list of lists, like `.append` in the first case):

```
with open("output.json", "w") as fp:
    fp.write("[")
    first = True
    # your API loop here
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            fp.write(", ")
        fp.write(json.dumps(response_json["result"]))
    fp.write("]")
```

OR (a list of dicts, like `.extend`):
replace this line:

```
fp.write(json.dumps(response_json["result"]))
```

with this one:

```
fp.write(json.dumps(response_json["result"])[1:-1])
# [1:-1] is a slice to remove the [ and ]
```

Comment: You say "This won't be a json...". Actually: `json.dump(hold_list, fp)` will make the `hold_list` a valid JSON and dump it into the `fp` file.